# CMFCPropertyPage::OnKillActive() is called before dialog box is shown

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

I have a dialog box based on the `CMFCPropertySheet` class. I add the first page in the constructor of my `CMFCPropertySheet` descendant and also set the  look (PropSheetLook_Tree) and some flags:

```
// constructor code
m_psh.dwFlags|=PSH_NOAPPLYNOW|PSH_NOCONTEXTHELP;        
m_psh.hwndParent=hwndParent; // hwndParent - parameter passed to the constructor
m_psh.hInstance=GetModuleHandle(L"mydll");
AddPage(&m_FirstPage);  
SetLook(CMFCPropertySheet::PropSheetLook_Tree,190);
```

`m_FirstPage` is a descendant of `CMFCPropertyPage`.

I also have other pages that I add later in `CMFCPropertySheet::InitNavigationControl()`

I overrode `CMFCPropertyPage::OnKillActive()` for each page to check if the entered data are correct on the page.

The problem is that `CMFCPropertyPage::OnKillActive()` of the first page (`m_FirstPage`) is called twice. The first time (unexpected) it's called before my dialog box even becomes visible. The second time - as expected - it's called when the user is switching the page or clicking the "OK" button . For the other pages, `OnKillActive()` is called only when clicking OK or switching the pages.

The problem is that during that first `m_FirstPage.OnKillActive()` call , there are no data on the first page yet. So my code shows an error message.

Is it normal that `OnKillActive()` is called twice for the first page? Is it always called twice like that?

Currently, I'm calling `IsWindowVisible()` in my `OnKillActive()` and if it's not visible I don't check the data on the page. Is this approach correct?

(The code is written in Visual Studio 2008)

**Update:**

call stack for the first unexpected OnKillActive() call

```
CFirstPage::OnKillActive()
CPropertyPage::OnNotify(unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=1196668, long * pResult=0x00123fc4)
CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message=78, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=1196668, long * pResult=0x00123ffc)
CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=78, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=1196668)
AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x00129370, HWND__ * hWnd=0x000a0348, unsigned int nMsg=78, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=1196668)
AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x000a0348, unsigned int nMsg=78, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=1196668)
// many calls that look like user32.dll!7e368734() 
ATL::CTraceFileAndLineInfo::operator()(unsigned long dwCategory=272, unsigned int nLevel=590706, const wchar_t * pszFmt=0x001d4008, ...)
// many calls that look like user32.dll!7e368734() 
CComCtlWrapper::_PropertySheetW(const _PROPSHEETHEADERW_V2 * unnamed1=0x00124f30)
AfxPropertySheetW(const _PROPSHEETHEADERW_V2 * unnamed1=0x00124f30)
CPropertySheet::DoModal()
OpenSettingsDlgBox(HWND__ * hwndParent=0x00040346)
// many calls that look like user32.dll!7e368734()
```

OpenSettingsDlgBox() is a dll function. It's called from another non MFC app

Comment: Or maybe test GetSafeHwnd() against NULL.

Comment: Give us the call stack for the first unexpected OnKillActive call!

Comment: @xMRi I've added the call stack

Comment: The must be more... Everything that causes the OnKillActive at the end is interesting...

Comment: @xMRi I've update the question. Showed all the constructor code. Expanded the call stack. And showed how I create and open the dialog

Comment: "_many calls that look like user32.dll!7e368734()_" - you should enable symbol server to see full call stack. Without symbols, call stack can be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet it's because of a call to [SetActivePage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a74afa35(v=vs.140).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(cpropertysheet%3A%3Asetactivepage)%3Bk(cpropertysheet.setactivepage)%3Bk(solutionitemsproject)%3Bk(devlang-c%2B%2B)&rd=true), or the equivalent SendMessage() call with [PSM_SETCURSEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), in the CPropertySheet-derived class's OnInitDialog function.

You should either (a) remove that call to SetActivePage or SendMessage(PSM_SETCURSEL), and just make the desired initial tab the first one, or (b) set valid initial data in the constructor for the CPropertyPage-derived class, or (c) set a flag to inhibit validation in the CPropertyPage-derived class until it's properly initialized.

Comment: I've commented out all the methods that I overrode in my `CMFCPropertySheet` and `CMFCPropertyPage` descendants. Except constructors, where I add now only 1 page, and except `OnKillActive`. Still `OnKillActive` is called when I'm calling `DoModal`. Also I noticed that `CMFCPropertySheet` constructor has `UINT iSelectPage = 0` as a default parameter. So maybe `SetActivePage` is called by MFC by design... Can you please tell me, what is the best method of `CPropertyPage` to set a flag to inhibit validation as you suggested in your option (c) ?